# How do I change the target library in wix code?

Tags: javascript, velo

I have a piece of code in wix that needs the `String.replaceAll` function but I got this errror:

`Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'string'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2021' or later.`

Is there a way in wix to change the compiler options?